# Power Factor Correction Controller IC limits

Tags: power-supply, power-factor-correction, controller

I've been considering throwing in an active PFC circuit into a high power PSU (about 5kW max surge at 240Vrms, 1400W typical), and while looking for an easy to use, low passive count controller, I found my way to TI's website, looking at datasheets for their controllers in which some state in their description (not the maximum ratings) as being "Suitable for 100-a few kW"..... I recall at least one saying "3kW", while most just don't state anything of the sort at all. In comparison, OnSemi has a line of IPM PFC's with integrated IGBT's, and to my understanding, the maximum power they can handle is limited only by the integrated switch and the passives/inductors, ie- 50A. Ignoring all of the passives, inductors, and the external FETs/IGBTs, what exactly is the limiting factor for TI's controllers, such as the UCC28070A or the UCC28180, and really any PFC controller in general? At no point do they ever specify where they got "a few kW" from, nor what "a few kW" means empirically. Not being all too familiar with PFC controllers, is it just a generalization, or is there actually some unspoken quantum-mechanics level reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

A controller like the [UCC28180](https://www.ti.com/product/UCC28180) (or generally, any switching power supply controller) is limited by the external components that it can practically drive. The extent of "practical" depends on the design requirements, e.g. efficiency, cost, size, which have a distinct relationship with the non-controller component selection.

The UCC28180 datasheet states that it has an "integrated 1.5-A and 2-A (SRC-SNK) peak gate drive output". In applications such as the [TIDA-010081](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-010081) 1 kW reference design, this is [circumvented (pg. 2)](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tidm325) by utilizing an additional driver IC, an [UCC27517](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc27517.pdf) to drive the [IPW60R060C7](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPW60R060C7-DS-v02_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462518ffd850151a130041f2b80) 600 V boost FET. The [PMP8740](https://www.ti.com/tool/PMP8740) 2 kW charger reference design goes even further, using two parallel UCC27517 driving [IPP65R125C7](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPP65R125C7-DS-v02_00-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30434208e5fd014209f7e8700375) 650 V FETs from the UCC28180 output. By comparison, the smaller reference designs like the [TIDA-01494](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-01494) 480 W supply, the UCC28180 is used to directly drive the [TK31N60X](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/product/mosfet/detail.TK31N60X.html) 600 V FET.

Another practical limitation is that this controller is only suitable for operating with single-phase input power. In the US, this would typically be 120 V at 15 A, usually leading to ~1200 W output supplies maximum. A full 2 kW of power supply, like in an [ATX supply](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/fsp-releases-2kw-mining-psu,35986.html) requires 230/240 V AC input to operate on a single phase. Even higher power would be served by a 20 or 50 A circuit or by expanding to [three phase power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power), which would require a different front-end PFC implementation.

To summarize, you cannot ignore the other components of the PFC implementation, the environment your implementation will be used in matters, and quantum mechanics need not be a thought in the engineer's mind when designing in a PFC controller.